# Symfony 3 don't send the form

Tags: forms, twig, symfony

I'm creating blog in Symfony 3.1.7 and i have a problem with sending the form. I created comment Entity Class. Then I generated form class by console end edited buildForm method. It looks like:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder
      ->add('content')
      ->add('save',ButtonType::class);
}
```

My controller looks like this

```
/**
 * @Route("/article/{id}", name="show_article")
 */
public function showAction( Post $post, Request $request )
{
$comment = new Comment;
$comment -> setPost($post);
$form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() ) {
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $em->persist($comment);
  $em->flush();
}
        return $this->render('default/show.html.twig',[
  'post' => $post,
  'form' => $form -> createView()
]);
}
```

Form is displayed by twig helper `{{form(form)}}`.

And the problem is when i try to send form. I clicked on button 
and nothing is happening. It looks like form was never subbmited.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SubmitType like so:

```
->add('save',SubmitType::class);
```

Comment: Thank you, fooled me [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/submit.html#attr).